# How to get custom attributes and values on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-attributes

[how can i get two values on wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkL2M.png)

```
`$kapidanGecer = $order->get_attribute( 'KapidanGecer' );
 $kacTane = $order->get_attribute( 'KacTane' );`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt this to fit your requirement (should be used from within the loop):

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta_value_key',true); ?>
```